# Why JavaScript Date object constructor doesn't work correctly?

Tags: javascript

Look at this code:

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date);
// Tue Apr 30 2013 14:24:49 GMT+0430

var date2 = new Date(
    date.getFullYear(),
    date.getMonth(),
    date.getDay(), 0, 0, 0, 0
)
console.log(date2)
// Tue Apr 02 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0430
```

I simply extracted some date from today's date, and created another date with that data, and the result is another date, not today. 
What's wrong with JavaScript's Date object?

Comment: Take a look at the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date Nothing wrong there

Comment: It uses zero based numbering like the rest of the system http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering

Comment: Also, unless you call this function at midnight, the time string will not match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.getDay()` returns the day of the week (0-6), not day of the month. (It returns 2 for Tuesday)

Use `getDate()` - it will return 30

Comment: And the other funny thing is that `getMonth()` starts with `0` for January and runs through `11` for December (not a problem here, but trips up many people, too).

Answer (score 1):

getDay() returns the day of the week (from 0 to 6), not the day of the month (1-31).
the correct method is getDate():

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date);
// Tue Apr 30 2013 14:24:49 GMT+0430

var date2 = new Date(
    date.getFullYear(),
    date.getMonth(),
    date.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0
)
console.log(date2)
// Tue Apr 30 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0430
```